# Using useState in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

Totally a beginner question, just trying to increment a variable when button is pressed which is successful tried to make a bit more interesting by making an if statement where count is set back to zero when it hits 10 but seems to not work

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const HelloWorldApp = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const counter = () => {
    if ( count > 10 )
    {
      count == 0;
    }
    setCount(count+1)
  }

  return (
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.baseText} >Hello, world! x{count}</Text>
      <Button onPress={counter} title="Click me!"/>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: "Cochin",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
});


export default HelloWorldApp;
```

Comment: You should use `setCount` when you want to change `count`. For example, `setCount(count > 10 ? 0 : count+1)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const counter = () => {
    if ( count >= 10 )
    {
     setCount(0)
     return
    }
    setCount(count+1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with condition in setCount..

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const HelloWorldApp = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const counter = () => {
    setCount((prev) => (prev >= 10 ? 0 : prev + 1));
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>Hello, world! x{count}</Text>
      <Button onPress={counter} title="Click me!" />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: "Cochin",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```